# Socket IO request Query String param meaning

Tags: websocket, socket.io

What is the function of each query string (EIO, transport, t) passed during each socket io connection request? And how to generate the t value?

[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  If you just get the socket.io client library, it will handle all this for you along with other socket.io specific stuff on top of a webSocket.